# Kaa Java SDK not syncing with KAA Sandbox MongoDB on AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, kaa

I have Kaa Sandbox installed on AWS using default values 'localhost' and port as '27017' in log appender. Is this correct?

Now running the Java SDK for "My first kaa app" is giving the following error on macOS.

error message: INFO org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultOperationTcpChannel - Can't sync. Channel [default_operation_tcp_channel] is waiting for CONNACK message + KAASYNC message

Is this a problem with the IP address/port mentioned in log appender or is this a problem with mongoDB? Is mongoDB installed by default with Kaa Sandbox on AWS or is it missing and needs to be installed separately?

Error msg also includes: [main] INFO org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.DefaultChannelManager - Failed to find operations service for channel [default_operation_tcp_channel] type TransportProtocolId [id=1456013202, version=1]

Comment: Please, post your fix as an answer, don't append it to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by using following steps: 1. Changed the ipaddress in the admin panel> general settings to my ec2 host IP address with port as 8080

Using SSH, logged into ec2, changed the user to user:kaa, password:kaa, used: sudo /usr/lib/kaa-sandbox/bin/change_kaa_host.sh host_ip
Downloaded the new SDK and created a new app. Data was received in mongoDB.

Comment: The only difference with your answer is that I connected into ec2 using: 'ssh -i /path/my-private-aws-instance-key.pem ubuntu@ec2-my-aws-instance-host.compute.amazonaws.com' and directly launched 'sudo /usr/lib/kaa-sandbox/bin/change_kaa_host.sh my-aws-instance-host-ip'. Anyway, many thanks Anil Sagar, you saved my day!