# Can't get CONNACK + KAASYNC message

Tags: mongodb, kaa, intel-edison

I have configured the Kaa Server on Ubuntu 14.04. I have chosen MongoDB as log appender. When i execute my SDK on the same ubuntu machine the data gets inserted into the Mongo Database. But when i try to execute the SDk on Intel Edison board it gives me Can't get CONNACK+KAASYNC message. I have followed all the rules for installing the Kaa Server.

the logs links are

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx5TGFxgyDWbSkZUVVUzbkhqSTA

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx5TGFxgyDWbalNBZkZBMmRtajQ

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened up the ports used by Kaa. If not Check "Firewall rules configuration" in this installation guide "http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Installation+guide"

Answer (score 0):

I think earlier, your app sdk and the kaa server must be on the same machine and hence you faced no issue. Now since intel edison needs to communicate with your kaa host as an external device, you need to configure your kaa host admin and also your log appenders with the external IP address of your kaa host. Pls refer to a similar issue mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585362/7269314)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to re-configure the Kaa instance for the correct 'Kaa host' setting, then regenerate the Kaa SDK and rebuild your application for Intel Edison board with that new SDK.

The 'Kaa host' should match the IP address of the host the kaa-node 
instance is running on and be accessible from the application side by that 
IP address. This configuration must be done before the SDK for the 
application is generated as the bootstrap IP addresses are embedded into 
the SDK.

Please check your node network configuration and re-generate the SDK for 
the application.